# How to make a socket client ready for sending and recieving without requiring an action from the server?

Tags: c#, python

I have a server.py socket code and client.py. Now I need the client to be always ready (in standby) to receive data even if it doesn't send any to the server. Can that be done ?

Comment: From your comment "in PVT", it seems you want to LISTEN IN C# and send in Python, but your question suggests the opposite. If that is the case, please clarify the question, explaining which language will send and which one will listen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose what you need is select module.

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/select/

The idea is that with the help of select you can wait for different types of events (read, write, exception) that happen on sockets passed to select's input.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to receive data sent from some C# code, which I handled in Python. It uses threads to "listen forever" while you perform stuff in other threads with the data received. Hope this helps:

```
import threading
import SocketServer


class UDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        ## DO SOMETHING USEFUL WITH WHAT YOU RECEIVE VIA self:
        data = self.request[0].strip()  # in this case, self.request[0] contains a string
        # etc.

class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        HOST = "192.168.1.23"
        PORT = 8888
        server = SocketServer.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), UDPHandler)
        server.serve_forever()

Listener().start()
```

Comment: friends , i need the client to just recieve data without sending acknowledge to the server

Comment: The code above doesn't send anything anywhere. It just listens (`Listener` class) "forever" (`serve_forever` method).